# How to get total comments and shares of a post including values on shared instances V2.9

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am using API version 2.9 
I would like to be able to get the the following values.

[image: Comments and shares on a post.]

Currently I am only able to retrieve comments and shares 'On Post' using

`FACEBOOK_ROOT_URL/POST_ID?fields=shares,comments`

In contrast I am able to get the total and 'On Post' values on reactions with which I can calculate the 'On Shares' value. For example in the context of likes...

[image: Likes on a post.]

The query: `FACEBOOK_ROOT_URL/POST_ID?fields=reactions.type(LIKE).summary(total_count),insights.metric(post_reactions_by_type_total)`

The `post_reactions_by_type_total` lists all of the reactions types and their totals while `reactions.type(LIKE).summary(total_count)` returns the 'On Post' likes. Are there a similar metrics related to comments and shares providing either the total or 'On Shares' value?

Comment: Have you checked what post insights metrics are available in the documentation yet?

Comment: @CBroe yup I have only been able to identify the shares and comments 'On Post'. I have gone through and tested all of the metrics and properties on the Post and the Pages/Post Insights API's that seemed even remotely  relevant and I haven't been able to identify the sum total or the 'On Shares' value for shares and comments.

Comment: I'm wondering if you found a solution to this since posting the question? I am also trying to get these counts in a way that aggregates across shares and not just the original post, and have not found a way to do so.

Comment: @mmccaff no sadly I have not found a solution yet.

Comment: @StrahinjaVladetic 2 years had passed. Still no answer? I am still having the same problem with v5.0 of the api